# Extract numbers within range python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, bigdata, matching

I have two datasets which are in a dictionary format:

```
ch1 = {1000: 128, 
       2830: 1022, 
       3438: 198, 
       5908: 109} 

ch2 = {1295:  1203, 
       2836: 1238, 
       4901: 8367, 
       7608: 249}
```

Currently, I have code to look for matches between keys in one dictionary and keys in the other:

```
coin = [int(ch1[key])+int(ch2[key]) for key in ch1.keys() & ch2.keys()]
```

I'm looking to change this code so that it finds keys that are within a given range of one another. For example, if within a range of 10, the output list from the example dictionaries would be `[2260]` as the sum of 1022+1238, by matching keys 2830 from dic1 and 2836 from dic2.

One limitation is the data files are large (~500Mb) which has limited the solutions I have thought iterating through list data.

In the rare case where there are two keys in one dictionary which are in the range of a key in the other dictionary, this should give one match.

```
ch1 = {1000: 128, 
       2830: 1022, 
       3438: 198, 
       5908: 109} 

ch2 = {1295:  1203, 
       2836: 1238, 
       2839: 8367, 
       7608: 249}
```

Should still yield `[5825]`, round((1238+8367)/2+1022).

In the even rarer case that there are two pairs, it does not matter which of these are matched together. There should be only two outputs in this case. Eg:

```
ch1 = {1000: 128, 
       2837: 1022, 
       2838: 198, 
       5908: 109} 

ch2 = {1295:  1203, 
       2836: 1238, 
       2839: 8367, 
       7608: 249}
```

Result = [2260, 8565] which comes from 1022+1238, 198+8367

Comment: What do you want/expect to happen if there are multiple keys that fit your range criterion? For example, change 4901 in the 2nd dictionary to 3439. Would you expect two values?

Comment: `0128` is a syntax error in python

Comment: Sorry, I have added in the potential exceptions and fixed the ch1 issue

Comment: Please add your code for the three criteria, your textual description is extremely confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a simple answer that runs in 9seconds for two dictionaries that are 15MB each (31MB total), so it may be used as a baseline for comparison. Which is the desired speed?

I don't sum the results but find all eligible pairs, as I believe I don't quite understand how should they be summed. I believe already having the combinations it can be quite easy to apply your own rules.

Create two dictionaries

```
import sys
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = rng = default_rng(12345)

MAX_KEY = 10000000
MAX_VALUE = 10000
M = 1000000

dictionaries = {'1': {}, '2':{}}

for i in range(M):
  for i in dictionaries:
    key = rng.integers(low=1, high=MAX_KEY)
    value = rng.integers(low=1, high=MAX_VALUE)
    dictionaries[i][key] = value
  
ch1 = dictionaries['1']
ch2 = dictionaries['2']

TOT_SIZE = 0
TOT_SIZE += sys.getsizeof(list(ch1))
TOT_SIZE += sys.getsizeof(list(ch2))
TOT_SIZE += sys.getsizeof([ch1[key] for key in ch1])
TOT_SIZE += sys.getsizeof([ch2[key] for key in ch2])

TOT_SIZE /= (1024**2)
print(f"TOT_SIZE = {TOT_SIZE} MB")
```

Function

```
def get_possiblePairs(TH = TH):
  
  possible_sums = {}
  list_keys = (list(ch1)+list(ch2))
  list_keys.sort()
  N = len(list_keys)

  possible_sums = {}
  coin_list = []
  for i in range(N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
      key1 = list_keys[i]
      key2 = list_keys[j]
      if key2<key1+TH:
        if key1 in ch1 and key2 in ch2:
          coin = ch1[key1] + ch2[key2]
          possible_sums[(key1,key2)] = coin
      else:
        break
  for j in range(N):
    for i in range(i+1, N):
      key1 = list_keys[i]
      key2 = list_keys[j]
      if key1<key2+TH:
        if key1 in ch1 and key2 in ch2:
          coin = ch1[key1] + ch2[key2]
          possible_sums[(key1,key2)] = coin
          
      else:
        break

  return possible_sums
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution posted by konrad-h, but I've decided to write mine which is somewhat simpler, and it appears to have less loops. However, it relies more on numpy functions, so I'm not sure which one is more efficient, and mine has a drawback - it won't work for the 3rd case.

I'll present the solution, and clarify why I think the 3rd case is difficult to solve regardless of the approach.

So, my approach is:

1.) Create numpy array of keys. I call these arrays `c1_keys` and `c2_keys`, for dictionaries `ch1` and `ch2` respectively.

2.) For every `key1` in `c1_keys`, I find **all keys** keys in `ch2_keys` which are `+-10` of `key1`.

3.) Create `avg_` of all `key2`'s found (their corresponding values from `ch2`).

4.) To list `results` append the sum of the `avg` and the value from `ch1` provided by `key1`.

5.) Remove found key2's from numpy array `ch2_keys`.

```
def find_pairs(ch1, ch2):
    # dict keys to np array
    c1_keys = np.array(list(ch1.keys()))
    c2_keys = np.array(list(ch2.keys()))

    results = []
    # find pairs of keys
    for key1 in c1_keys:
        indices = np.logical_and(key1 - 10 <= c2_keys, c2_keys <= key1 + 10)
        sum_ = 0
        if np.any(indices):
            for index in c2_keys[indices]:
                sum_ += ch2[index]
            sum_ = sum_ / indices.sum()
            results.append(round(ch1[key1] + sum_))
            c2_keys = c2_keys[~indices]
    return results
```

**Pro's:**

-This solution will work faster and faster as the search progresses, because we're removing keys from the 2nd dictionary (that is, from the np.array)

-It will solve the most common and the rare case

**Con's:**

-Won't solve the 3rd case.

Explanation:

As @konrad-h has stated as well, he didn't know how to sum the eligible pairs, because it's somewhat confusing. This is why his solution has more loops. Suppose the dictionaries look like this:

```
ch1 = {
    1: 100,
    2: 200,
    3: 300,
    ...
}

ch2 = {
    1: 100,
    2: 200,
    3: 300,
    ...
}
```

How should we deal with this? For a `+-10` tolerance, all keys 1-10 in ch1 will be compatible with all keys 1-10 from ch2. The only way that we can know that perfect pairs exist, is to do the complete search two times. First, we find all eligible pairs (which is what konrad-h) did. Second, we find the best pair combos (which also isn't simple).

This is why I highly suggest you reduce the accepted tolerance and sum the first eligible pairs you encounter. There is no way to know if two pairs in `ch1` and `ch2` exist, without passing through them twice. But you can easily do cases 1 and c2.